# Modify one value in text with type "json"

Tags: regex

Im getting the following value as text and I need just to replace the value inside APPLICATION_TEST **app_name** to **helloWorld** instead of **h10**,How can I do that?

The text file contain many properties and I need to modify just APPLICATION_TEST property

```
APPLICATION_TEST='{\"instance_id\":\"78-bdc\",\"app_name\":\"h10\",\"started_at_timestamp\":\"14\",\"state_timestamp\":\"195\",\"host\":\"mo-d6fa32e73.mo.sap.corp\""app_uris\":[\"\"],\"uris\":[\"zo-\"]}'\r\nHOST.corp\r\n"
```

I try with   `var app = /(APPLICATION_TEST=[^:]*):\d+/gi;` 
and wanted to do replace after but without sucess ... any idea

Comment: then use json. parse and change it

Comment: That's not a valid string. It contains JSON, which should be parsed as such, but it's got escaped characters for some odd reason even though they don't need to be escaped. Lots of stuff to fix before you start hacking at it with Regex

Comment: @RGraham - This is what I got in the text file and I cannot change it...I need just to search for the key APPLICATION_TEST and inside it replace the value of the app_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex to match the string up to the necessary `app_name` value, capture it into Group 1 and then back-reference to it in the replacement string with `$1` and then use your desired value instead of the previous value:

```js
document.write("<b>Old string from the original question</b>:<br/>");
var APPLICATION_TEST = "APPLICATION_TEST='{\"instance_id\":\"78-bdc\",\"app_name\":\"h10\",\"started_at_timestamp\":\"14\",\"state_timestamp\":\"195\",\"host\":\"mo-d6fa32e73.mo.sap.corp\"app_uris\":[\"\"],\"uris\":[\"zo-\"]}'\r\nHOST.corp\r\n";
var res = APPLICATION_TEST.replace(/(APPLICATION_TEST\s*=\s*'\s*\{[^{}]*"app_name"\s*:\s*")[^"]+/, '$1helloWorld');
document.write(res + "<br/><br/><b>Now comes the JSON-compliant string</b>:<br/>");

// Or, since the string you might have is actually a JSON string:
var s = '{"instance_id":"718-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc","app_name":"hw10"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(s);
obj.app_name = "helloWorld";
s = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.write(s + "<br/><br/><b>A regex solution for the JSON-compliant string</b>:<br/>");

// Regex way
var s = '{"instance_id":"718-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc","app_name":"hw10"}';
document.write(s.replace(/("app_name"\s*:\s*")[^"]+/, '$1helloWorld') + "<br/><br/><b>Or, if your string is something like you posted before...</b>:<br/>");

// Or if your string is in fact similar to the one you posted before:
var APPLICATION_TEST = "APPLICATION_TEST='{\"instance_id\":\"718-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc\",\"app_name\":\"hw10\"}'";
document.write(APPLICATION_TEST.replace(/(APPLICATION_TEST\s*=\s*'\s*\{[^{}]*"app_name"\s*:\s*")[^"]+/, "$1helloWorld"));
```

Comment: I tried to use your string as is, but there is an unescaped double quote here: `corp\""app_uris`. I just removed it for testing.

Comment: Thanks 1+ this is what I want :) but its not working any idea why (the value is not updated...

Comment: Where doesn't it get updated? In the file? As you see from the demo, the `res` variable gets modified.

Comment: I think that maybe since I put the value from the debugger in my post ,assume that the value is inside "json like" which is '{"instance_id":"718-8fcf-546bb7b7cbdc","app_name":"hw10"}' (this is the value of filed APPLICATION_TEST inside my text file...how would you do it ?

Comment: Since it is proper JSON, you can actually use JSON to parse it. Or do you insist on a regex? I added all options, please choose to your liking.

Comment: I want to avoid it and use regex instead is it possible ?

Comment: I added 2 regex ways at the bottom (2 last blocks). Doesn't either of them work for you? If not, please check if you shared exact input string.

Comment: Thanks I need somehow combine what you provide /("app_name"\s*:\s*")[^"]+/, '$1helloWorld' with (/(APPLICATION_TEST\s*=\s*'\s*\{[^{}] ,how can I do that since the first option is not working and In the second option you ignore the filed APPLICATION_TEST

Comment: I do not ignore: `document.write(APPLICATION_TEST.replace(/(APPLICATION_TEST\s*=\s*'\s*\{[^{}]*"app_name"\s*:\s*")[^"]+/, "$1helloWorld"));`. See the last option at the bottom of the snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87239/discussion-between-shopia-t-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 2):

Use `APPLICATION_TEST.app_name= 'helloWorld';`   as you are getting APPLICATION_TEST as an Json object.

```js
var APPLICATION_TEST={"instance_id":"78-bdc", "app_name":"h10", "started_at_timestamp":"14", "state_timestamp":"195", "host":"mo-d6fa32e73.mo.sap.corp", "app_uris":[""], "uris":["zo-"]};
alert(APPLICATION_TEST.app_name);

APPLICATION_TEST.app_name= 'helloWorld';
alert(APPLICATION_TEST.app_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `replace` function of javascript as

```
APPLICATION_TEST = APPLICATION_TEST.replace('app_name','helloWorld');
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsisodia91/d9d9scks/1/)

Comment: Thanks but the text document is contain many fields besideAPPLICATION_TEST  And I need to do it with regex...I cannot change other content...

Comment: This will not answer OPs question as you are changing `'app_name'` rather than `'h10'` to `helloWorld`.

Comment: OP has stated that he want to replace `app_name` rather than `h10` @Asunez

Comment: @shopiaT Can you please be more specific to this many fields mean with the same name or with different name

Comment: @NarendraSisodia - For example I've fields APPLICATION_TEST ,APPLICATION_TEST2 ,foo, bar etc I just need to get the value of filed APPLICATION_TEST and modify the value of app_name to hello world , I need to do it with regex ,can you assist please?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia **The value of** app_name

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex: `\b(APPLICATION_TEST)(=.*app_name\\":\\")(\w+)`

Then substitute with this: `$1$2helloWorld`

Don't know javascript but this seems legit as I check for *APPLICATION_TEST* literally if it exists with first group and then swap third matchgroup with `helloWorld`. You might need to tweak this if your names contain other characters.

Live demo here: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fJ4pX3/4)

EDIT: Changed the lookbehind to a normal group as JS doesn't support lookbehind.
EDIT v2: Changed the boundaries to not match `2APPLICATION_TEST` or `APPLICATION_TEST12`. Regex101 link updated

Comment: Thanks 1+ I try it but when I put var vc = /(?<=APPLICATION_TEST)(.*app_name\\":\\")(\w+)/;    I got errror , any idea how to adopt it?

Comment: @shopiaT My bad, I wasn't using the JS flavor and didn't notice there is no such thing as lookbehind in JS. See my edited answer for an answer that should be working in JS properly. Note that the substituted string is now the third group, not second.

Comment: @shopiaT Updated once more, try it now. (Was matching also wrong names such as `APPLICATION_TEST2`, now it should work properly.